# Parse - Migration issue - Files are missed

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Accidentally my existing classes under Core in parse are missing, Due to this i couldn't login with existing user, how do revert back my existing tables?

Comment: referring to your own instance of Parse-server or on Parse.com ?

Comment: is that possible to get those tables from mongodb link, which is given by parse?

Comment: If deleted then no. If you have backups setup then yes. But I will need to understand your environment better!

Comment: Hey Cliffordwh, I just migrated application from parse to back4app. then I tried to delete and create new from back4app. I faced this issue., Is that possible to import files from that migrated URL string?

Comment: Yes, as long as its still present on parse.com